# Force item on flexbox to stay on top

Tags: css, html, flexbox

The idea here is to have a placeholder with a set of links on the left and an image on the right. As you press the links the image and the description below changes.

So far I have this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <style type="text/css">
    .flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
   }

   .flex-item {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
   }

   .flex-item img{
       flex-grow:0;
       flex-shrink:0;
   }

   span {
    margin-top: 0px;
        padding-right: 1em;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="flex-container">
         <div class="flex-item">
          <span>
     <a href="#">link text</a></p>
     <a href="#">link text</a></p>
     <a href="#">link text</a></p>
          </span>
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/41/Iceberg_with_hole_near_Sandersons_Hope_2007-07-28_2.jpg/800px-Iceberg_with_hole_near_Sandersons_Hope_2007-07-28_2.jpg">
         </div>
     </div>
     <span>Description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description </span>
 </body>
 </html>
```

How can I force the links (the `span` element) to align on the top of the parent (same height as the start of the image) instead of centered on the middle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `align-items` value

```
.flex-item {
    display: flex;
    /*align-items: center; */ /* remove this */
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: center; */
  /* remove this */
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.flex-item img {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

span {
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <span>
  <a href="#">link text</a>
  <a href="#">link text</a>
  <a href="#">link text</a>
  </span>
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/640/300">>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description description</p>
```

Comment: Well, derp. Thanks